# Regex for the last line of a string

Tags: regular-expressions, string

I'm trying to search for the last line in a string (lines separated by `\n`) using string match but I cannot make it work as intended. The code below evaluates to 0 while I would have expected 4. I guess my regex is wrong (it was supposed to be a newline (`\n`) followed by anything but a newline (`.*`) until the end of the string (`$`).

```
(string-match "\n.*$" "\n \n \n ")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$` matches at the end of a line, not the end of a string. If you want to match at the end of a string you need to use the `\'` operator:

```
(string-match "\n.*\\'" "\n \n \n ")
=> 4
```

See `(info "(elisp)Regexp Backslash")` for more details (or [Regexp-Backslash](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Backslash.html))